# How to find and ban some devices from my wifi using the command line?

Tags: network, linux, nmap, network-scanners, internet

I use Arch Linux. I just installed some packages such as `nmap`, `netdiscover` and others. It is a [ubiquiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquiti_Networks) internet network, for the sharing of connection to several routers. There are about 7 routers connected to the same internet network.

How to get the list of users connected to my Wifi by using the command line, and then to block them?

After some research, I discovered a tool called **Kickthemout** but this tool does not work often on some devices.

I used to try with netdiscover or nmap but sometimes the result is wrong, my own smartphone is connected and I do not see it with those tools.

Answer (score 0):

`nmap` is a port scanning tool. It will allow you to find nodes which are routable/accessible in the ranges you specify. `nmap` will not reveal the network configuration settings on those hosts from a port scan.

If you are within the [broadcast domain](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-collision-domain-and-broadcast-domain) you could listen for traffic going outside of the network and analyse based on MAC addresses to see which endpoints in this network segment are going through the router.

Perhaps you are asking about why you are finding devices outside of your local subnet? That just means that those addresses are routable from your router, they may not be *directly* connected to your local router.

---

I will update my answer if you modify your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool to perform a scan in this situation is:

[arpscan](http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/~jb/arpscan/)

This will perform a scan based on an interface. In other words, it will work on the **layer between MAC and IP** (hence ARP scan). This will ensure your results will be limited only to **hosts connected directly to your router** (provided you do not use ARP proxy or something similar.
(Do not confuse this with arp-scan - available on most distros, and make sure you make a donation - this is a really useful tools for LAN admins).